# angular material textarea rows css not working

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am Using angular Material design and i used Textarea but the height is not change is fixed i tried so many ways but not working i like want

However, it is always the same size. Even Change css Also but its just changing height and i can say its not working

***Any idea on how to change the size of the textarea?***

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width">
      <mat-label>Discription</mat-label>
      <textarea matInput></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
```

***Even I Tried This But same issue am getting***

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
  <textarea matInput formControlName="description" matTextareaAutosize matAutosizeMinRows=1 matAutosizeMaxRows=5></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

This Output i am getting  form code

[image: Demo]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Comment: If i try this also .  ---    <textarea matInput rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="text"></textarea>

Answer (score 2):

You need to add:

```
matAutosizeMinRows=5 matAutosizeMaxRows=20
```

This will set a minimum number of rows and the maximum number of rows which control the height also.

If you tried the above, as you edited the question, and you are getting a different results. Then probably another CSS overrides the `textarea` height. Check with your developer tool to find out other CSS attached to the `textarea`.

Comment: The `StackBlitz` is not accessible anymore. Is it possible to update it someways please?

Answer (score 0):

set `line-height` style for `textarea`.

e.g:

```
<mat-form-field >
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Description" style="line-height: 20px !important"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```